# Move my replies to another folder

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I want a VBA macro code for Outlook 2010 to move my manager requests mails from my inbox to another folder in case I reply.

Comment: set up a rule instead.

Answer (score 1):

A rule really is the best solution for this, as @Bathsheba mentioned. Or, if you must do a VBA macro, I'd suggest recording a macro, then editing in VBA editor as required:
1. Click **Tools**, **Macro**.
2. Record macro.

Comment: Thanx Aaron, actully i'm going to try recording it. but how can i differentiate the sender?

Comment: You may try checking [here](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV808000379990&lcid=1033&NS=OUTLOOK%2EDEV&Version=12&respos=0&CTT=1&queryid=164e2982%2D6371%2D4ade%2Db9ba%2D1dc11a33ab5d) for more details.

Comment: appreciate your efforts Aaron :D

Comment: @enderland: At least some versions do have VBA macro recorder. My 2007 standard comes with it. Besides, the question was for VBA macro coding.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is the answer. Thanks to Graham Mayor www.gmayor.com

It checks for messages from strAddress in the default Inbox and those that have been replied to are moved to the sub folder of Inbox defined as strFolder - here 'Test'.

If you want to check all messages then remove the lines marked '*****

```
Sub MoveReplied()
Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim i As Long
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strAddress As String
    strAddress = "someoneATsomewhere.com"
    strFolder = "Test"

    Set olItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
    olItems.Sort "[Received]", True
    For i = olItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set olItem = olItems(i)
        If olItem.SenderEmailAddress = strAddress Then '*****
            If Not olItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003") = 0 Then
                olItem.Move Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).folders(strFolder)
            End If
        End If '*****
    Next i
Cleanup:
    Set olItems = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Best regards =)